# Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://hub.docker.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

When running

```
docker login hub.docker.com
Username: bheng
Password: **********
```

I kept getting

> Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://hub.docker.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found

How do I know what is my username ?

I can log in into my docker hub fine with the same credentials.

[image]

I've tried almost every combinations

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your login is `bheng`, but `hub.docker.com`(`[SERVER]`) is wrong. Correct server is `index.docker.io`. Actually, it is default server, so you don't need to specify, so just use the simple command:

```
docker login
```